# Chrome extension - encrypting data to be stored in chrome storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, encryption, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which stores some user data locally using the [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API.

So, quoting from the documentation:

> Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted.

Anyway I would like to encrypt my extension's data before storing it, and I'd like to know: does Google provide a way to do this? And, if not, is there  any other way?

Comment: It is possible to encrypt the data; the difficulty is in finding a way to get a secret key that is not visible to attackers.

Comment: If you plan to store sensitive data, add support for Google Drive or Dropbox into your extension and store the data there. You can further protect the data by forcing the user to sign in to retrieve their data from the cloud. However, if someone has physical access to your computer, then you've got bigger problems ;).

Answer (score 0):

Encryption is the easy part, it can be done with any other API available to the web, like the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API).

The issue is that there's **no way to safely persist the encryption key or passcode** locally. Alternatives include:

- your own server-based authenticated API to remotely store and retrieve this key
- have the user enter a passcode at some point and just keep it in memory (for example using the [`chrome.storage.session` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/session)), but lose it when the browser is closed.

These two methods are used by password managers and cryptocurrency wallets for example.