# What type of security should be included in chrome extensions?

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension

My friends and I are trying to build a chrome extension using node.js, node-mysql, and mysql. We were able to build a simple extension that uses the chrome history API and stores our data into our mysql database. More or less, we understand how to move the data around, but we are completely lost on security.

We have no idea what to google or look for. How can we improve the security of a Chrome extension that will store and analyze important user information (of course, we intend to tell users we are doing this)?

Anything would be helpful, even just a list of terms we should look in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot store data on the client side in a 100% secure way, so you should store it in your server (if you have any)**. Quoting from the [Chrome developers guide on the storage APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage):

> Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted.

The above quote applies to any `chrome.storage.*` API, plus the `localStorage` API. By the way there are several methods to store data in a "safer" way, even thought that **data stored on the client side of a Chrome Extension is never entirely safe**. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826998/chrome-extension-encrypting-data-to-be-stored-in-chrome-storage/27838218#27838218) of mine for some **partial** security measures you can manage to add to your extension as a developer.

Comment: @Alan  if this answer solves your question, please consider marking it as correct, to let people with the same problem find the solution easily.

Comment: For the record, `chrome.identity` is a secure storage for OAuth tokens. But it's not general-purpose storage.